# Split data from single cell into multiple records

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with an `Invoice` field that contains values and dates. There can be more than one invoice per record. If so, the invoices are listed separated by line breaks *within a single cell*. An example is shown below.

```
 PO #   PO Date   PO Amt        Invoice
  1     05/19/15   100        100 06/01/15
                              500 07/1/15
                              1000 08/1/15
  2     05/20/15   101        100 06/01/15
                              500 07/1/15
                              1000 08/1/15
  3     05/21/15   102        100 06/01/15
                              500 07/1/15
                              1000 08/1/15
```

I want to split up these records that have more than one invoice listed. I would like to create new rows for each invoice. The new rows should have the same data in the other fields. Here's how the sample data should look when this is done:

```
PO #    PO Date   PO Amt     Invoice
1       05/19/15   100     100 06/01/15
1       05/19/15   100     500 07/1/15
1       05/19/15   100     1000 08/1/15
2       05/20/15   101     100 06/01/15
2       05/20/15   101     500 07/1/15
2       05/20/15   101     1000 08/1/15
3       05/21/15   102     100 06/01/15
3       05/21/15   102     500 07/1/15
3       05/21/15   102     1000 08/1/15
```

Doing this manually would take forever. How can I split these records this way in Excel?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Just posting data here is not sufficient to asking a specific question. Please read **[ask]**, then update your question to include details of what you have attempted so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: You have quotes around three rows of the Invoice column.  Is that a single, wrapped cell?  Do all POs have three datasets in the Invoice column?

Comment: sorry I don't know why the quotes were there but I took it off. yes it's a single cell. Some POs might have 2 datasets or 1 or 4 or 5 it's all different.

Comment: @Phi Bach We still need more information.  A legitimate answer to your current question is "Do it manually with copy/paste."  Not to be mean about it, but i'm making a point to fix your question after checking out that link CharlieRB gave you.  The site is meant for specific questions, not broad topics that have many different answers.

Comment: I've edited your post pretty thoroughly. Feel free to roll back my edit if you feel it misrepresents your question or otherwise steps on your toes. I the problem needed clarification because I initially misunderstood the issue completely and didn't want anyone else to waste time answering the wrong question.

Comment: if i got you right... its as good as impossible without vba... at least, it would be faster to do it manually than just with formulas...

Comment: Do the invoice cells use line breaks or simple wrapping based on column width?

Answer (score 0):

I still want to give it a shot :D

- at `A:D` is your data
- i assume `E:Z` is empty

We start at:
[image]
now in `E2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D2,"
",";")
```

(Alt+Enter for line break inside the cell)
Now we pull it down till the end of the table.
Highlight column `E`
 - copy
 - paste (values only)
 - in "Data"-Tab use "Text to Columns" ->  seperated ->
  uncheck all except semicolon -> finish

our table now should look like this:
[image]
now comes the fun part: formulas :D
i'll start at `M2` (adjust it if needet)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$I$999,(ROW()-MOD(ROW()-2,5)-2)/5+1,MOD(ROW()-2,5)+1),"")
```

and pull it down as needed... note: adjust `$E$2:$I$999` as u like... but don't forget the `$`
Now for `J2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$999,(ROW()-MOD(ROW()-2,5)-2)/5+1),"") (note: NO $ in front of the A!)
```

drag it to `L2` and then down for all 3 columns
[image]

Now comes the magic: select column `M` and hit filter -> uncheck `0` and `empty`
[image]

select the whole list now and copy it -> paste it to another sheet (values only like the last time)

Now copy/paste the headers and you are done :)